# How do you append one jsexpr to another jsexpr in racket

Tags: json, append, scheme, racket

I'm trying to concactenate two json files together. if i do them directly then 
there is problem of paranthesis. I want them two concactenate as two jsexp and then write to an output file. How would you concactenate two jsexpr in racket ?

```
(define (write-or-append-to-json destfile newfile)  

 (define full-json
  (lambda (json-str)
   (let ((jsexp (string->jsexpr json-str)))
    (hash-refs jsexp '()))))

 (let ((dest-json #f)
       (new-json #f))
 (set! new-json (full-json (file->string newfile)))

 (if (file-exists? destfile)     

     (begin ;insert insert-what of newjson into destjson
      (set! dest-json (full-json (file->string destfile)))
      (delete-file destfile)

      ;;Append two jsexp together. i.e. append new-json info to dest-json)
     (begin ;json does not exist, simply create it          
      (write-json new-json destfile)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library produces immutable hash tables instead of lists, and there is no such thing as `hash-append`. The easiest way to define a `hash-append` seems to involve converting all hashes to lists and then back again:

```
(define (hash-append . hashes)
    (make-immutable-hasheq
       (apply append
          (map hash->list hashes))))
```

If the same identifier appears twice, then the second instance supersedes
the first, which is the same thing that JavaScript would do if you evaluated  JSON with duplicate keys directly.

Answer (score 2):

Simple appending using a list of the contents of two files:

```
(define (concat-json-files file1 file2 outfile)
  (define json1 (call-with-input-file* file1 read-json))
  (define json2 (call-with-input-file* file2 read-json))
  (define out (list json1 json2))
  (call-with-output-file* outfile #:exists 'truncate
    (λ(o) (write-json out o))))
```

If you want to merge two json objects, you need to do that on the two hash tables on the Racket side.  Quick example:

```
(define (concat-json-files file1 file2 outfile)
  (define json1 (call-with-input-file* file1 read-json))
  (define json2 (call-with-input-file* file2 read-json))
  (define out (make-hash))
  (for* ([json (in-list (list json1 json2))]
         [(k v) (in-hash json)])
    (hash-set! out k v))
  (call-with-output-file* outfile #:exists 'truncate
    (λ(o) (write-json out o))))
```